# Date range parameters in VB6 Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I'm creating a form that calls a report.

I created a report with Parameters and a Formula:

```
?FromDate
?ToDate
@DateRange = If {Database.Date} >= ?FromDate And {Database.Date} <= ?ToDate
Then "Show"
Else "Hide"
```

And I created a source code to transfer the two date inputs:

```
Dim Date1 As String
Dim Date2 As String
If optDaily.Value = True Then
    Date1 = txtDate1
    Date2 = txtDate1
ElseIf optWeekly.Value = True Then
    Date1 = txtDate1
    Date2 = txtDate2
End If
With Report1
    .ParameterFields(0) = "CDate(#" & Date1 & "#)"
    .ParameterFields(1) = "CDate(#" & Date2 & "#)"
    .Formulas(0) = "DateRange = 'Date Range : " & Date1 & " To " & Date2 & "'"
    .ReportFileName = "C:\Location\Report.rpt"
    .Action = 1
End With
```

When I execute the code, the application returns an error:

```
Runtime-error: '20553'
Invalid parameter field name
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed the problem by changing the parameters to formulas and wrote this code:

```
.Formulas(0) = "FromDate = #" & CDate(Date1) & "#"
.Formulas(1) = "ToDate = #" & CDate(Date2) & "#"
```

So my next problem is this: how do I hide the details if it's out of date range?

Comment: If you debug this, at what line do you get the error?

Comment: It highlights the line .Action = 1. When I hover the mouse at the line, it says ".Action = <Property is write-only>"

Comment: Okay, so it's throwing the error when it tries to actually show the report.  In the two lines you have where you set the .ParameterFields,  you use an index, have you tried using the field names instead?  For instance .ParameterFields("FromDate") --if that's the name of the field name in the crystal report.

Comment: I haven't tested that. I'll try it if it works.

Comment: `.ParameterFields("FromDate") = "CDate(#" & Date1 & "#)"`  `.ParameterFields("ToDate") = "CDate(#" & Date2 & "#)"`

Comment: Just tested it. The error is now "Type mismatch" or .ParameterFields("FromDate") = <Type mismatch>

Comment: That sounds like your dates variables are different types in the report than what you are passing into the parameters.  You're attempting to pass dates to your report; is your report expecting dates or is it expecting strings?

Comment: On second thought, look at this link. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9263/How-to-pass-discrete-parameters-to-Crystal-Reports)  I'm not sure you can pass parameters the way you are doing, but my Crystal is pretty rusty :)

Comment: My report is expecting dates because I set the data type of the parameters to date.

Comment: Assign parameters as dates: `.ParameterFields(0) = CDate(Date1)`

Comment: @Arvo tried this. Didn't work